# Меню навигации, добавить Item вниз

Tags: android, menu

Всем доброго времни суток. Скажите пожалуйста, у меня с сервера подгружается список категорий, которые в последующем я вставляю в список item'ов меню. Проблема такова, в layout.xml у меня есть два item'a, Войти и Выход, но когда список подгружается он подгружается в самый низ, т.е. после  Войти и Выход. Сам вопрос: Как подгрузить список item'ов которые будут отображаться в самом верху? А за ранее созданные айтемы опустить в самый низ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте им расположение сделать 99 и 100 соответственно, и они всегда должны быть внизу.

```
android:orderInCategory="100"
```

Comment: Большое спасибо)